# How to calculate the sum total of separated group field in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I am making a report in "SAP Crystal Reports" and I need to calculate the sum total of the group field. Report is grouped by user name, I made the "Running Total Fields" field and it calculates all of them as in example below:

```
UserName 1                   2
                             3
                             1
                        -----------
                             6

UserName 2                   1
                             2
                        -----------
                             9   <------- I need here 3
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

- edit the running total field and reset it after each group (it is now generating a total for all records).
- use a summarized field - select the field in the `details` section and choose Insert | Summarized Field...

I would also suggest reading a book on the topic.

Comment: The first option helped. Thanks.